# Spring boot Caching with Hazelcast

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast

I want to implement Caching for my spring boot application. I am using Hazelcast. Every time during startup i want to build a global cache with some data that is frequently used in the application and is not evicted. Is this the right way to do?
Can anyone suggest some standards and strategies that are used for caching in a spring boot web application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check [Hazelcast Code Samples: Hazelcast Integration](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration), there are plenty of examples of Spring Boot + Hazelcast. If you want just the simplest usage, take a look at [this](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/blob/master/hazelcast-integration/spring-cache-manager/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/spring/cache/CachingConfiguration.java).

If you need some more info about the architectures you can use, take a look at this [blog post](https://hazelcast.com/blog/architectural-patterns-for-caching-microservices/).

Comment: Thank you very much